# Не получается войти в систему на KDE Plasma 5 Manjaro Linux

Tags: linux, archlinux, kde, manjaro

Ранее пользовался только операционной системой Windows, решил перейти на Linux. Благополучно поставил Manjaro Linux с средой KDE Plasma(Всё скачивал с официального сайта, версия, как я понимаю, последняя) на ноутбук. Установка прошла вполне успешно, после установки настроил оформление рабочего стола, больше в системе ничего не трогал, но, к сожалению, на следующий день она отказывается запускаться. Дальше экрана ввода пароля пройти не удаётся. После ввода пароля переходит на экран загрузки, на котором система и зависает. Пробовал открыть консоль при помощи Ctrl+Alt+F2, но после этого система также зависает и остаётся лишь чёрный экран. Самому разобраться оказалось проблематично(

Comment: А какое у вас кол-во ОЗУ?

Comment: 8 гб, устанавливал систему без свапа

Comment: Вроде бы swap нужен,  не уверен,  переустановите на автомате

Comment: @CeramicThree Своп нужен даже если у вас 100500 гигов памяти.

Comment: Что у вас за видеокарта?

Comment: @Oxyd Своп тут не причём. Всю жизнь пользуюсь линуксом без свопа.

Comment: Могу предположить, что система обновилась, вы её выключили, а после включения она зависает из за установленных драйверов, которые не совместимы с железом... Но это всё гадание и тыкание пальцем в небо. Сам не верю в то что написал :) Проще всего не гадать, а переустановить систему и желательно (чтобы проверить, действительно ли в железе прична) с другой графической оболочкой или другой дистрибутив.

Comment: @Oxyd GTX 1050Ti

Comment: @BeastWinterwolfто что вы что-то делаете всю жизнь, совершенно не означает, что вы всю жизнь это делаете правильно.

Comment: @CeramicThree При установке вы выбирали свободные или проприетарные драйвера?

Comment: @Oxyd Свободные